Am I Able To Import Local Packages To Script NodeJS?
I have a monorepo as such:
packages

api
data
scripts
utils

There are index.js in the ones that export modules, respectively. And package.json for each.
I have a script in the scripts directory and import a module from the utils folder with:
const { moduleName } = require('@packages/utils')
However, I keep getting the cjsloader error:
> @packages/scripts@1.0.0 myScript
> node -r dotenv/config --max-old-space-size=8192 ./data/myScript.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@packages/utils'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Me\Code\referral-domain\packages\scripts\data\myScript.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Me\Code\referral-domain\packages\scripts\data\myScript.js:3:42)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Me\\Code\\referral-domain\\packages\\scripts\\data\\myScript.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.18.2

Am I supposed to specifically yarn install in this scripts directory? When I try that, it tries to get @packages from npm registry, which is incorrect since it's a local package.
I also tried using '../../utils' which seemed to at least make the import error go away. Although then it can't find require('aws-resource-library').tools
{
  "name": "@packages/scripts",
  "main": "index.js",
  "description": "Scripts.",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
      "@packages/data": "1.0.0",
      "@packages/utils": "1.0.0",
      "api-clients": "git+https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/api-clients#3.3.10",
      "aws-resource-library": "git+https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/aws-resource-library#0.0.158",
      "@app/opensearch-library": "^0.2.0"
},
  "devDependencies": {
      "dotenv": "8.2.0"
}

}

Which version of yarn?  You should run your project with yarn node myScript.js so that it can initialize yarn's pnp loader for you.  Otherwise you can manually call the pnp loader (if that's what you're using) with require('./.pnp.cjs').setup();

Is your package.json at scripts/data/packages.json?  Did you yarn install from the scripts/data folder?  Do you use the workspaces feature?  Presumably you added the dependency with yarn add @packages/utils@../../utils?  It would be helpful to see your package.json dependencies and to know the exact folder structure.

Yarn 1.22.21 and Node 18 (although I can downgrade to 16 or 14 if need be).

@Wyck added scripts/package.json. Running yarn in both scripts and scripts/data both give me the npm registry install issue.

Oh I needed to run yarn bootstrap to get packages to index or whatever.

In this case I had to run yarn bootstrap, which rebuilds dependencies and modules for every part of the monorepo.
